# How to show images that have been uploaded to site by users, on page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, show

So I have created a php file that allows users to upload images to a directory (/uploads), now I wish to allow them to see these images on a page, I've heard that you can use JavaScript for this? If so, How would I do that?

Here's the code I have so far;

HTML (Basic Upload form);

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Upload_file;

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$allowedTypes = array("image/gif",'..','..',"image/png");

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedTypes))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
header('Location: index.html');
   }
 }
}
else
   {
echo "Invalid file";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either replace `header('Location: index.html');` and replace it by : `echo '<img src="upload/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . '" />';` which will display the picture on the php upload file (admitting it's a file which is supposed to display content and not just a back end file as it seems to be as you want to user to be redirected to index.html).

The best way and most convenient way to do that is to save the picture path, or name (`"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]`) in a mysql table to e able to retreive it as you please.
You might want to have a look over tehre : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Comment: I basically want to redirect the user to a page where all the images that have been uploaded will be displayed, allowing them to view there own image that they uploaded as well as others.

Comment: The most efficient way to do that is to save all those file names to a sql table and enquire the file names on the page you want them displayed on. I obviously cannot code that for you but you can do some research about sql tables and php and if you understand the basics you'll be able to work it out or at least come back here and give us a  bit of code to work from.

Comment: It will make your life a lot easier if you used [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) @Cwtch22

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want users to see these images. I'm assuming you mean that any image uploaded can be viewed by anybody (not on a per user basis). One way you could do this without modifying your existing code would be to get a list all image files in PHP from the uploads folder. For example, you could have a file showimage.php containing:

```
<?php
$imgArray = scandir("upload");
foreach($imgArray as $img){
echo "<img src='" . $img . "' />";
}
?>
```

The scandir function lists all files http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Also, I'm assuming your uploads folder only contains images. If you have other files in there, you could use the glob function instead (once for each type). https://www.php.net/glob

Edit: Also, as the other poster stated, if you want to do anything else with these images, it might be a good idea to store their paths (with the user who uploaded them) so you can retrieve it in a more direct way.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, where would all the images appear? On what page?

Comment: This could be on a new separate page and you could change your header redirect to go to this new page after upload, or you could put this snippet anywhere I think.

Comment: So, how would I make these images appear on the page I want? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If my code snippet works as intended it should work on any page where the upload folder is in the same directory.